# Using form values for where command

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a question about the `where` command. I have this form element in my database table with a lot of columns and I need to search specific values: customers and type. As shown below...

```
    <form action="{{ route(shop.find) }}">
    <select class="form-control"  name="customers1" id="customers1">
    @foreach ($customers as $key => $value)
    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" name="type1" id="type1">
    @foreach ($types as $key => $value)
    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
    </form>
```

In my controller, I am stuck at the `where` command.

```
public function find(Request $request){
$customers = DB::table("tbl_customers")->pluck('name','id')->where('name', '=', $request->name);

//This where command is absolutely wrong. I need the right ways to do it. 
$types = DB::table("tbl_types")->pluck('race','raceid')->where('race', '=', $request->race);

return view('shop.find',compact('customers', 'types'));}
```

I don't know what I need. Or what I need to use. I hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `pluck()->where()` you're loading all rows and then working with the collection. The correct syntax is:

```
public function find(Request $request)
{
    $customers = DB::table("tbl_customers")->where('name', $request->name)->pluck('name', 'id');
    $types = DB::table("tbl_types")->where('race', $request->race)->pluck('race', 'raceid');
    return view('shop.find', compact('customers', 'types'));
}
```

Comment: It's worked great. But i need a second question. $customers and $types variables are must in same variable. So i can show them in the page with using foreach. In these case i cant use them with same foreach cycle. What should i do? I hope i can clear. Can you suggest a method or smt. Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @AliÖzen please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: There collections will have different size. If you still want to iterate over them, you could use the `$loop` variable. `@foreach ($customers as $customer) {{ $customer->name }} {{ $types[$loop->index]->id }} @endforeach`